# Location for floorplan

Tags: raster, proj, tilemill, mapbox

Is there an application / service where I can put my floorplan of a building en 'position' it on the right place on the earth? (The buildings location).

I found TileMill an application where I can import an raster image in. Howerver the image covers the entire world.

When importing I supplied an 900913 'string' with some information about the location and size I presume.

```
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over
```

With the above string the building 'covers' the entire earth. Is there a way to get the 'correct' string so I can place it over the correct building?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your data.  Is it originally CAD and what is the origin(is it a nominal 0,0 location as opposed to a real-world georeferenced location?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Tile Mill, but if you have ArcMap you can do this fairly easily by importing the image and Geo-referencing it, the advantage of this is if you're using version 10 or later you can use ArcMap's base data feature to use satellite imagery as a background, and then just align your floor plan based on that.

Here's a guide on how to georeference in ArcMap...

http://ocw.tufts.edu/data/54/626689.pdf

If you don't have ArcMap, the same thing can also be done in QGIS (which is free) however it may be more difficult to find a satellite image to align your floor plan to. Here is a guide in QGIS...

http://www.netpalantir.it/news/index/how-to-georeference-an-image

Comment: +1, also just FYI, but QGIS has an "OpenLayers" Plugin that includes base imagery from Google, OpenStreetMap, Yahoo, and Bing. It's easy to install through the built-in Plugin fetch/management interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The other options will work, but you can also do this in Google Earth Pro

https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148099?hl=en